# Sharepoint is installed but still get the error "Sharepoint server must be installed on this computer"

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

I am a newbie and I have installed Win server 2003, SP 2007 and VS 2010 for creating a web part. However, when I try creating a web part, it says

> A sharepoint Server is not installed on this computer. A Sharepoint server must be installed to work with Sharepoint projects

Please help!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because the out-of-the-box Visual Studio 2010 templates are meant for SharePoint 2010 development. If you want to use Visual Studio 2010 for SharePoint 2007 development, you cannot use these templates.

Comment: then how can I create a web part to be used in SP 2007. I do not want to uninstall vs 2010 and install VS 2008 again. Please help

Comment: @techguy: You can create a simple class library and begin web part development on top of that